# Можно ли использовать локальные переменные в функциональном программировании?

Tags: java, kotlin, функциональное-программирование

Если в функции объявить какую-то локальную переменную, это будет считаться чистой функцией? Вне области видимости этой функции, состояние программы не меняется, при одинаковых входных данных, всегда результат один и тот же, значение входных параметров не изменяются.

```
fun test(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
  val i = a/2
  return i + b
}
```

Comment: Вы фактически сами положительно ответили на свой вопрос.  Если функция детерминирована (результат одинаков для одинаковых входных параметров) и не обладает побочными эффектами (не меняется состояние за пределами функции), то она является чистой.  Использование локальных переменных в данном случае -- это несущественная деталь реализации, так как локальные переменные создаются при каждом вызове функции и ограничены её областью видимости.

Comment: Связывание имени со значением есть практически в любом функциональном языке, в т.ч. чисто функциональных. Пользуйтесь :)